# How to parse a markdown file to json in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, pyparsing

I have many markdown files with titles, subheadings, sub-subheadings etc.

I'm interested in parsing them into a JSON that'll separate for each heading the text and "subheadings" in it.

For example, I've got the following markdown file, I want it to be parsed into something of the form:

```markdown
outer1
outer2

# title 1
text1.1

## title 1.1
text1.1.1

# title 2
text 2.1
```

to:

```json
{
  "text": [
    "outer1",
    "outer2"
  ],
  "inner": [
    {
      "section": [
        {
          "title": "title 1",
          "inner": [
            {
              "text": [
                "text1.1"
              ],
              "inner": [
                {
                  "section": [
                    {
                      "title": "title 1.1",
                      "inner": [
                        {
                          "text": [
                            "text1.1.1"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "title 2",
          "inner": [
            {
              "text": [
                "text2.1"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To further illustrate the need - notice how the inner heading is nested inside the outer one, whereas the 2nd outer heading is not.

I tried using `pyparser` to solve this but it seems to me that it's not able to achieve this because to get section "title 2" to be on the same level as "title 1" I need some sort of "counting logic" to check that the number or "#" in the new header is less than or equal which is something I can't seem to do.

Is this an issue with the expressibility of `pyparser`? Is there another kind of parser that could achieve this?

I could implement this in pure python but I wanted to do something better.

---

Here is my current `pyparsing` implementation which doesn't work as explained above:

```
section = pp.Forward()("section")
inner_block = pp.Forward()("inner")

start_section = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word("#"))
title_section = line
title = start_section.suppress() + title_section('title')

line = pp.Combine(
pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.unicode.Latin1.printables), stop_on=pp.LineEnd()),
join_string=' ', adjacent=False)
text = \~title + pp.OneOrMore(line, stop_on=(pp.LineEnd() + pp.FollowedBy("#")))

inner_block \<\< pp.Group(section | (text('text') + pp.Optional(section.set_parse_action(foo))))

section \<\< pp.Group(title + pp.Optional(inner_block))

markdown = pp.OneOrMore(inner_block)


test = """\
out1
out2

# title 1
text1.1

# title 2
text2.1

"""

res = markdown.parse_string(test, parse_all=True).as_dict()
test_eq(res, dict(
    inner=[
        dict(
            text = ["out1", "out2"],
            section=[
                dict(title="title 1", inner=[
                    dict(
                        text=["text1.1"]
                    ),
                ]),
                dict(title="title 2", inner=[
                    dict(
                        text=["text2.1"]
                    ),
                ]),
            ]
        )
    ]
))
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a slightly different approach to this problem, using `scan_string` instead of `parse_string`, and doing more of the data structure management and storage in a `scan_string` loop instead of in the parser itself with parse actions.

`scan_string` scans the input and for each match found, returns the matched tokens as a `ParseResults`, and the start and end locations of the match in the source string.

Starting with an import, I define an expression for a title line:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# define a pyparsing expression that will match a line with leading '#'s
title = pp.AtLineStart(pp.Word("#")) + pp.rest_of_line
```

To get ready to gather data by title, I define a `title_stack` list, and a `last_end` int to keep track of the end of the last title found (so we can slice out the contents of the last title that was parsed). I initialize this stack with a fake entry representing the start of the file:

```
# initialize title_stack with level-0 title at the start of the file
title_stack.append([0, '<start of file>'])
```

Here is the scan loop using scan_string:

```
for t, start, end in title.scan_string(sample):
    # save content since last title in the last item in title_stack
    title_stack[-1].append(sample[last_end:start].lstrip("\n"))

    # add a new entry to title_stack
    marker, title_content = t
    level = len(marker)
    title_stack.append([level, title_content.lstrip()])

    # update last_end to the end of the current match
    last_end = end

# add trailing text to the final parsed title
title_stack[-1].append(sample[last_end:])
```

At this point, title_stack contains a list of 3-element lists, the title level, the title text, and the body text for that title. Here is the output for your sample markdown:

```
[[0, '<start of file>', 'outer1\nouter2\n\n'],
 [1, 'title 1', 'text1.1\n\n'],
 [2, 'title 1.1', 'text1.1.1\n\n'],
 [3, 'title 1.1.1', 'text 1.1.1\n\n'],
 [1, 'title 2', 'text 2.1']]
```

From here, you should be able to walk this list and convert it into your desired tree structure.